# Excel formula C6*E6 returns different values in two different worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that is calculating quantity * unit price for a construction estimate.  In worksheet 1 for the first building, unit price is "m" as a placeholder and the value returned is 0 (the desired result).  In worksheet 2 for the second building, the same formula is returning #VALUE.  The problem is that I need a running sum of what's being entered.  In the second worksheet, the sum is also #VALUE but in the first worksheet, I can at least see the running sum while I'm working.

I've done a formula evaluation and there is no difference other than the outcome.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact content and format of the cells for formula refers to?

Comment: Sounds like the numbers in the other spreadsheet are actually text.

Comment: We just changed the formula in the 2nd and subsequent worksheets (there are 42 of them) to say ISERROR(C6*E6,0) or something like that.  It's good for now. Thank you for offering to help.